# Getting IHostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath inside DatabaseInitializer

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to seed my db with some data stored in json files.

I need to inject an `IHostingEnvironment` inside my `IDatabaseInitializer.Seed()` method so I can read the json files using `IHostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath`.

This property is injected by the main container by default but the constructor of an `DbConfiguration` must be parameterless, so I can't pipe `IHostingEnvironment` through `DbConfiguration` into `SetDatabaseInitializer(new DatabaseInitializer())`.

```cs
/*
* Database Context
*/
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(DatabaseConfiguration))]
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public DatabaseContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

/*
* Database Configuration
*/
public class DatabaseConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    // Can't receive injected IHostingEnvironment env because constructor must be parameterless
    public DatabaseConfiguration()
    {
        SetProviderServices("System.Data.SqlClient", SqlProviderServices.Instance);

        // Could pass IHostingEnvironment through constructor
        SetDatabaseInitializer(new DatabaseInitializer()); 
    }
}

/*
* Database Initializer
*/
public class DatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DatabaseContext>
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment env;

    // Receives IHostingEnvironment from DatabaseConfiguration
    public DatabaseInitializer(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        this.env = env;
    }

    protected override void Seed(DatabaseContext context)
    {
        // Read some .json files
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the main problem is that you can't use DI in migration code.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to read those files then? (Considering that the `ContentRootPath` is tied to `IHostingEnvironment`)

Comment: can't you use `DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(MyConfiguration(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath));` and have it flow down to the `DatabaseInitializer`?

Comment: @MickaëlDerriey I've added some code samples for better clarification of the problem. DbConfiguration has to have a parameterless constructor; otherwise I could inject it without any problems.

Comment: But instead of using the `DbConfigurationType` attribute to set the `DbConfiguration`, couldn't you just use the [`DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbconfiguration.setconfiguration(v=vs.113).aspx) static method which allows you to pass an instance of the configuration? You could do so in your `Startup` where you have access to `IHostingEnvironment`.

Comment: @MickaëlDerriey The ctor of an `DbConfiguration` must be parameterless, so it's not possible.

Comment: I understand it needs to be parameter-less if you use the `DbConfigurationType` attribute to set it because EF wouldn't know what values to inject, but nothing prevents you from having a parameterized constructor if you call it yourself. I just tried and it works as expected.

Comment: @MickaëlDerriey As I'm trying to explain... Even if you use SetConfiguration you'll have a runtime exception about the parameterless constructor.

Comment: @MickaëlDerriey I'm providing you exactly the stacktrace showing that this solution does not work: [stacktrace-aspnet-core](https://s29.postimg.org/qar3sevzb/Capturar1.png)

Comment: Could you try calling `DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration` earlier in the process? I think doing in the constructor of the `DbContext` is too late, and it should only be called once in the lifetime of the application, too. I would suggest doing it in `Startup` since you need an instance of `IHostingEnvironment`.

Comment: @MickaëlDerriey Yep I'm sorry; you were right. Calling it inside the constructor is too late for binding the configuration into the context, doing that causes the exception. Putting it in the `Startup` constructor worked as it should. Still I'm opening an issue on the aspnet core github because this workaround is a little bit ugly. We should be able to inject it directly. I can see other uses for `IHostingEnvironment` besides in `Startup` class

Comment: glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

I'm initializing my db, and had to write a separate class, which I call from configure, you could do the same thing and pass in the path as a parameter

Here's how I call it:

```
        using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            // Initialise Database
            var initializer = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IDbInitializer>();
            initializer.SeedAsync().Wait();

            // initialize plugin manager
            var manager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IPluginManager>();
            manager.Initialize(dbConnection);
            if (Configuration.GetSection("PluginService").GetValue<bool>("RunAtStartup") == true)
                manager.Start();
        }
```

and here's the db initialize class

```
    public interface IDbInitializer
{
    Task SeedAsync();
}

public class DbInitializer : IDbInitializer
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public DbInitializer(ApplicationDbContext context,
                         RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
                         UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _context = context;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task SeedAsync()
    {
        await CreateRolesAsync();
        await CreateAdminUserAsync();
        await SeedMenuAsync();
    }

    private async Task CreateRolesAsync()
    {
        List<IdentityRole> roles = new List<IdentityRole>();
        roles.Add(new IdentityRole { Name = "Admin", NormalizedName = "ADMINISTRATOR" });
        roles.Add(new IdentityRole { Name = "Member", NormalizedName = "MEMBER" });                     // An email confirmed memeber
        roles.Add(new IdentityRole { Name = "Guest", NormalizedName = "GUEST" });                       // Used for a user that has only checked out as guest
        roles.Add(new IdentityRole { Name = "NotConfirmed", NormalizedName = "NOTCONFIRMED" });         // Used when a guest hasnt confirmed there registration

        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            var roleExists = await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role.Name);
            if (!roleExists)
            {
                await _roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
            }
        }
    }

    ...
```

Hope that helps